# Make a c# list show the same item for the whole day and then another random element for the next day?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, timer

A question right now i am randomly picking out elements from a list and showing them to the user which changes with every page refresh of asp.net.

However i want to display one element for the whole day and then another on the next day and so on.

My code for randomly picking out list elements is:

```
  public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        byte[] box = new byte[1];
        do provider.GetBytes(box);
        while (!(box[0] < n * (Byte.MaxValue / n)));
        int k = (box[0] % n);
        n--;
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }

    return list.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have different random sequences for different users, or the same random sequence for all users for a particular day?

Comment: All the users will see the same record for a day

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Random` class to shuffle your list, and provide `seed` value, depending on current day:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Today.Ticks));  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Because you'll initialize `Random` instance with the same seed across whole day, you'll get the same sequence of numbers generated by `rng.Next` method.

To get the same, single item every time you refresh within the same day, you don't need to shuffle your collection:

```
public static T GetRandomItemForToday<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random(unchecked((int)DateTime.Today.Ticks));  
    return list[rng.Next(list.Count)];
}
```

Comment: BUT Random does not take a double as a parameter.

Comment: Hi, can we compare(take modulus of) Random and count of the list? Unable to cast object of type 'System.Random' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Tried it out it still seems to be changing the values on page refresh and with navigation to different pages

Comment: Is the collection that is passed to that method the same across calls?